# Shutdown and Reboot commands result int black screen with blinking dash

Tags: shutdown, unity-dash, 17.10, reboot

I have a issue with my freshly installed ubuntu 17.10 artful installation. Everytime when I try to execute a shutdown or reboot command (even the shutdown and reboot buttons of the gnome desktop) I get a black screen with a blinking dash and the computer won't shut down completely.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?